# Polymer dom-if loops and types

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I want to love polymer, I really do. I watched the youtube videos when I first heard of it, and I wanted to get into this whole developing idea, but its so bloody hard!

So I am creating my polymer module to create a REST test page for whatever properties are given to it.

I started by creating a working test page, fine great everything works. Changing that to create a test page based on its properties is a pain.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[restServices]]" as="service">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[inputs]]" as="input">
                        <div id="[[service]]" style="padding-left:80px;padding-top:30px;">
                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{getCheck(input.[[service]])}}">
                                        <my-hello
                                        id = "getbutton"
                                        uri=[[uri]]
                                        onchange
                                        ></my-hello>
                            </template>
                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{getIdCheck(input.[[service]])}}">
                                        <my-getid
                                        id = "getidbutton"
                                        uri=[[uri]]
                                        onchange
                                        ></my-getid>

                            </template>
                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{postCheck(input.[[service]])}}">
                                        <my-post
                                        id = "postbutton"
                                        uri=[[uri]]
                                        onchange
                                        inputs = item.value
                                        >
                                        </my-post>
                            </template>
                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{putCheck(input.[[service]])}}">
                                        <my-put
                                        id = "putbutton"
                                        uri=[[uri]]
                                        onchange
                                        inputs = item.value
                                        >
                                        </my-put>

                            </template>
                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{deleteCheck(input.[[service]])}}">
                                        <my-delete
                                        id = "deletebutton"
                                        uri=[[uri]]
                                        onchange
                                        ></my-delete>
                            </template>
                        </div>
        </template>

    </template>
```

And the properties used.

```
restServices:{
            type: Array,
            value:["GET","POST"]
        },
        inputs:{
            type:Array,
            value:  [{



                    "GET":[],
                    "POST": [
                            {"label":"id","id":"id"},
                            {"label":"topicID","id":"topicID"},
                            {"label":"postUserID","id":"postUserID"},
                            {"label":"postUserID","id":"fromUserID"},
                            {"label":"points","id":"points"},
                            {"label":"rateDate","id":"rateDate"}
                    ]


            }
            ]
        },
```

The If functions called.

```
    getCheck: function (inputType) {
        return inputType == "GET";
    },
    getIdCheck: function (inputType) {
        return inputType == "GETID";
    },
    postCheck: function (inputType) {
        return inputType == "POST";
    },
    putCheck: function (inputType) {
        return inputType == "PUT";
    },
    deleteCheck: function (inputType) {
        return inputType == "DELETE";
    }
```

Err: Polymer::Attributes: couldn`t decode Array as JSON

None of the If functions gets called.

I have read so much, gone looking through so many examples and I have tried so many different things. I feel like throwing the computer out the window.

Cannot debug this stuff, and it makes it so difficult to work with.

Comment: Hi Murphy what are the data you are getting in restServices

Comment: The restServices and inputs properties are the only 2 I am dealing with right now. The others are fine. The errors all come from the dom-if templates.

Comment: Here are some errors in your code. `id="[[service]]"` will not work. You need to id like this `id$="[[service]]"`. In `{{postCheck(input.[[service]])}}` is `[[service]]` another `binding`? I don't think it'll work. `input.service` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will give it a go. It is all very confusing as to the rules of it all imo.

Comment: The error is gone and the event handler is hit, only problem is no value is passed. You might be right that my loop within a loop won't work the way I want.